# PHPunit fails on generating code coverage report

Tags: php, phpunit, code-coverage

When I run phpunit like that:

```
  ./vendor/bin/phpunit tests --coverage-html=coverage --configuration /var/www/phpunit.xml
```

The tests pass, but i get error on generating coverage report

```
    Generating code coverage report in HTML format ... Not found
```

what can i do? can i get more info to debug?